# Brackets around a very tall matrix

Tags: latex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
A  =
\bigg[
\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1 \\
\end{smallmatrix}
\bigg]
\noindent
```

Comment: Hello! Non-programming related questions about TeX/LaTeX should be directed to [Latex SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In this case, you probably just was to use `bsmallmatrix` in place of `smallmatrix`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a practical programming problem.

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you process the code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?  See [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tabularray` package with its math library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
A  =
\begin{+bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1 \\
\end{+bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]